# Need SQL query to solve this question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across an SQL question, want to know how to do that.

Question is this:-

> There is a table in SQL Server named
>   MyOrganisation having two columns -
>   Employee, Reporting_to.

It shows which employee reports to which employee.

I have to retrieve a resultset which contains two columns -

one--which stores employee's name and the other column stores the names of the employees which report to the employee in first column.

Please note that the order of the column which stores the name of the heads(to which employees report) has to be according to the hierarchy of the employees, like the head of the organisation has to be on number one.

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    mo1.Employee as boss,
    mo1.Employee as underling
from MyOrganisation mo1
join MyOrganisation mo2 on mo2.Reporting_to = mo1.Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

For example we have the Employee table holds the employeeid,employee name and other data

```
select e1.Name As Employee, e2.Name As Director
from MyOrganisation mo
join Employee e1 on mo.Employee = e1.EmployeeId
join Employee e2 on mo.Reporting_To = e2.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Using this approach you you have to add a further join for each potential level in the hierarchy, right?

Comment: I assumed that the names are in a different table than the MyOrgisation. If names are in the same table(MyOrginisation) then @Bohemians answer matches better your case